# Image not displaying on select option using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form which is supposed to show users with their uploaded images on the right of their names.
I have uploaded their images using:

```
require 'db.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $num=rand(1000000,10000000);
    $target_file = $target_dir ."$num". basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    extract($_POST);
$result=mysqli($conn, $sql);
    }
```

Below is the code that would display users' image together with their name:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rowUser['id']; ?>"><?php echo "<img src='uploads/".$rowUser['photo']."' >";?><?php echo $rowUser['name']; ?></option>
```

The images wouldn't display on coming to the users page. Only the name would come up. Am willing to learn and open to any solution you might have. Thanks

Comment: where do you add the photo to the user row?

Comment: i have used sql to insert the image, name to the db

Comment: Where? Can we see it?

Comment: @delboy1978uk here it is  "$sql="INSERT INTO `user`( `name`, `phone` `photo`)
            VALUES ('$name','$phone','$target_file')"; " i forgot to include it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not displayed because `<option>` [is allowed to contain text only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).

If you would like your options to contain images in it, you should use a JS solution like [selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). Such libraries solve the problem by creating something that behaves like a select control with options, but it's actually made of `divs` and `spans`.

Comment: @Georgey Ivanov does that mean there's no other way rather than js?

Comment: @DennyWaitley, if the task is to have "select options with images" - then indeed JS is the only way.